# bindingRoutingKey with multiple keys not work

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I want to filter the rabbit mq queue message with the specified routing keys, below are my configuration in the application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.subscription-changed-input.consumer.bindingRoutingKeyDelimiter=,
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.subscription-changed-input.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=#.CORE.#, #.LIFE_CYCLE.#, #.TERMS.#
```

But after i update the configuration like this, all the message is filtered in my queue. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.
The spring cloud stream rabbit version is :3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Figure out this issue by myself. The root cause is the space between each routing key. Just change the routing keys from:

```
#.CORE.#, #.LIFE_CYCLE.#, #.SUBSCRIPTION_TERMS.#, #.SNAPSHOT.#
```

to:

```
#.CORE.#,#.LIFE_CYCLE.#,#.SUBSCRIPTION_TERMS.#,#.SNAPSHOT.#
```

Then the configuration is working as expected. But I do think the spring cloud stream should do the trim for the configuration.

Comment: RabbitMQ allows leading and trailing spaces in routing keys, so the framework cannot arbitrarily trim them.